# Contar los input[] en javascripts

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código donde creo input[] con un boton pero quiero calcular el total de input agregado para ese valor multiplicarlo en otra funcion en javascripts

```js
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  
  <script>
  function add_fields() {
           var d = document.getElementById("content");

           d.innerHTML += "<br />  <input type='text' name='id_tecnico[]''  value=''  placeholder='Codigo' class='form-control'>";
        }
        
        function contar (){
          if ($('input[name=id_tecnico]').val().length != 0) {
                contar += 1;
            } 
            alert(contar);
        }
        </script>
```

```html
 <div id="content">
   <input type="text" name="id_tecnico[]"  value=""  placeholder="Codigo" >
 </div>
   <input type="button" id="more_fields" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add_fields();" value="Otro" />
```

Comment: que es lo que te no te funciona, que se ejecute la función? o que no te cuente los inputs? , cuando debería ejecutarse el contador de inputs?, deberías agregar esa información también, para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
  

  function add_fields() {
           var d = document.getElementById("content");

           d.innerHTML += "<br />  <input type='text' name='id_tecnico[]''  value=''  placeholder='Codigo' class='form-control'>";
           contar();
        }
        
        function contar (){
          var inputs = $('input[name^=id_tecnico]');
          var count = inputs.length;
          alert(count);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="content">
   <input type="text" name="id_tecnico[]"  value=""  placeholder="Codigo" >
 </div>
   <input type="button" id="more_fields" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add_fields();" value="Otro" />
```

Comment: disculpa una consulta hay alguna forma que me cuente solo los inputs que tengan data

Comment: Tendrias que hacer un bucle para recorrer todos los inputs y chequear que el valor no este vacio.

Comment: realize este bucle he igual me cuenta todos `for (j=0; j<inputs.length; j++) {
              if (inputs[j]!='') {
                contar+=1;
              }`

Comment: Tienes que comparar el valor de el input, no el input mismo: `if (inputs[j].value != '') {`

Comment: denuevo muchas gracias !

Comment: No hay de queso.